# How to send HTTP Post request to a socket using ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, tcp, http-post

I'm developing on my project and I'm new to ASP.NET.

I want to send HTTP post request to a socket when I hit a button

here is my code.

```
protect void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   socket clientSocket = new Socket (addressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, Protocol.TCP);
   clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPont.Parse("192.168.1.1", 5550));

   A = "1"; // i want to send this variable using HTTP post request

   clientSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.Getbytes(A));

   clientSocket.Close();
}
```

tnx for helping.

Comment: What is `socket`? Is this supposed to be `Socket` (as in `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`? Also if you're working with Http then the preferred method would be to use the `HttpClient` class.

Comment: Either HttpClient, or maybe `WebClient` or `WebRequest`. Definitely not a socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like the code below to send an HTTP request using POST Method...

A socket (Server + Port) will be automatically created to handle the data on the server to process the request.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";


string postData = "Data to post here"

byte[] post = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData); 

//Set the Content Type     
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";     
request.ContentLength = post.Length;      
Stream reqdataStream = request.GetRequestStream();     
// Write the data to the request stream.     
reqdataStream.Write(post, 0, post.Length);      
reqdataStream.Close();      
// If required by the server, set the credentials.     
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;     

WebResponse response = null;     
try     
{
    // Get the response.         
    response = request.GetResponse();      
}   
catch (Exception ex)     
{         
    Response.Write("Error Occured.");     
}
```

Hope this helps..